# Cpu shows very lows temperatures

Tags: cpu-temperature

I just built a new computer:

```
 CPU:Intel Core i5 6600k
 MOBO:GA-Z170X-GAMING 5 (REV 1.0)
 COOLER: Cooler Master EVO 212
```

The problem is that I got impossibly low CPU temperatures on my system (-1°C, -5°C , 0°C, 3°C ), even on, and before the CPU stress test (TJ MAX set to 85° Celsius). On maximum stress, the CPU gets 33°C:

[image: impossible temps]

My ambient temperature is 20°. All drivers are updated except for the BIOS.

When I touch the CPU cooler I feel that is a little warm (not cold, not extremely hot) but I am pretty sure that the sensors are not working well.

Should I update the BIOS and try again or should I ignore this temp?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the temperatures in the BIOS? It could be a software issue, have a look at [CoreTemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) and see what that says.

Answer (score 3):

It was a software issue.

RealTemp shows the wrongs values, so I checked the BIOS temps and downloaded CPUID HW Monitor.  These show much more coherent temps: min 17°C on idle, and max 51°C on load.

Comment: 17°C on idle??? Either you are sitting on Mount Everest or that is a wrong reading as well.